# Final Fantasy 7 Cloud Saves On PC

Tags: pc, final-fantasy-7

Just bought FF7 on Steam and I am having an issue with the syncing of my saved games to my Square Enix account. The issue is I'm looking into using the character booster that is offered with the cloud save feature.

I have 3 achievements, 4 save files, enabled cloud saving, linked my Steam account - and it still says no saved games.

I filed a help desk tickets with SE (not sure if that's going to anything), I'm pretty sure this isn't a Steam issue.

Does anyone have any information on how to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the servers that Square Enix uses are just crap and go down all the time for days on end.

I ended up using Black Chocobo to modify my save instead of using their cloud storage system.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are you're saving locally. Go into the configuration on the FF7 startup panel and enable cloud saves.